# Wordpress the_content <!-- more --> issue?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a function to decide what the length of my articles are (below). The issue is that on my index page, the_content seems to be 'split up' by my `<!-- more -->` tags.

For example, my article is 3000 characters long, but my index page only shows 500 characters before the 'Read More' link appears. My function uses the 500 characters as the_content instead of the actual 3000 characters. The length is shown as **Short**, even though the full articles is considered **Long**.

However on the full article page, where all 3000 characters are shown, the function works fine.

**Now my question is:** is there an alternative for the_content that ALWAYS uses the full article instead of what's currently shown on the page?

```
function wcount(){
ob_start();
the_content();
$content = ob_get_clean();
$length = strlen($content);
if ($length > 2000) { 
        return 'Long'; 

    } else if ($length > 1000) { 
        return 'Medium'; 

    } else if ($length <  1000) { 
        return 'Short'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the code? Is it something from your template or something you're suggesting?

Comment: I added the function below the question.

Comment: What do you mean? Where did that code come from - is it something you wrote or something from your template?

Comment: The code is in my functions.php. I call it using <?php echo $wcount(); ?> in my template. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Right! If you want to display a whole unedited post, why are you counting the words?sorry to keep asking qs, just trying to get a full picture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function wcount($post) {
    $length = strlen($post->post_content);
    if ($length > 2000) { 
            return 'Long'; 

        } else if ($length > 1000) { 
            return 'Medium'; 

        } else if ($length <  1000) { 
            return 'Short'; 
        }
}
```

Then call wcount() from within the post loop with something like `echo wcount($post);`

Answer (score 0):

Try
    global $more;
       $more = 0;
       the_content();

Comment: Hi,sorry, I did that on my phone, so kind of rushed it. Did you put that into your template where you want the content to appear - so instead of just <?php the_content ?>

Comment: looks like yo got it from above :)